# NHibernate updates all children when I update the parent

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate

User owns many UserItems.

```
    [Set(0, Cascade = "all-delete-orphan", Lazy = CollectionLazy.False)]
    [Key(1, Column = "user_id")]
    [OneToMany(2, ClassType = typeof(UserItem))]
    public virtual ISet<UserItem> Items { get { return _items; } set { _items = value; } }
```

Every UserItem has a reference to User:

```
    [ManyToOne(Name = "User", Lazy = Laziness.False, Column = "user_id")]
    protected virtual User User { get; set; }
```

The problem is that when I modify only User properties and Update it nh generates update query for every UserItem. I don't change Items property or any of properties on any of children.

Isn't nh supposed to properly track changes like this? I wish only changed children to be updated when I update the parent.

**UPDATE**
I think I understood why it doesn't work for me but I don't know how to fix it. I keep User entity in memory while he is connected. I can't use one session to do all the operations with User (because there may be thousands of connected Users). So I open session, get User and close the session. Then I make some changes to User, open session again and call Update. The new session doesn't keep track of that User instance changes. So what should I do?

Comment: Please provide a working example to reproduce it. I cannot reproduce it with the code provided...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question *(the updated part)* would be the [9.4.2. Updating detached objects](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-updating-detached). There is detailed explanation of the `SaveOrUpdate()` and `Merge()` methods. The **Merge** is what will solve your issue, an extract:

> ... using `Merge(Object o)`. **This method copies the state of the given
>   object onto the persistent object with the same identifier.** If there
>   is no persistent instance currently associated with the session, it
>   will be loaded. The method returns the persistent instance. If the
>   given instance is unsaved or does not exist in the database,
>   NHibernate will save it and return it as a newly persistent instance.
>   Otherwise, the given instance does not become associated with the
>   session. **In most applications with detached objects,** you need both
>   methods, `SaveOrUpdate()` and `Merge()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an entity which is detached from its session, you are right, the change tracking doesn't work properly.

To update it again, you have to get the entity again via `session.Get(...)` by Id (you should have the Id because you have the object with the Id in memory... 
Then make the changes on that **new** object and call `session.Update`.

Or use `merge` to let nh handle that for you

```
session.Update(session.Merge(item))
```

Comment: Could I use Merge()? I have a dettached User entity, make changes on it, than create a new session, start transaction, call session.Merge(user) and commit, will it work correctly?

Comment: Yep merge is more or less meant to handle that. Remember that merge just returns the merged object.

Answer (score 0):

Use Cascade type as Select

```
 [ManyToOne(Name = "User", Lazy = Laziness.False, Column = "user_id",cascade=CascadeType.SELECT)]
protected virtual User User { get; set; }
```